# Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 45030 [preauth]

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

```
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 45030 [preauth]
Nov  9 17:40:01 swi007 sshd[17716]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 45032 [preauth]
Nov  9 17:42:30 swi007 sshd[17840]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 45074 [preauth]
Nov  9 17:42:30 swi007 sshd[17850]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 45076 [preauth]
```

This is what happens when I start ssh auth - it creates a 450xx port.

Comment: Where do you get that output from?

Comment: from the /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Ok. It's the port that the client uses to connect to the ssh server. Do you try to ssh from the local machine to the local machine (e.g. `ssh user@localhost`)?

Comment: yes i try ssh to localhost

Comment: Ok. Please include the output of `ssh -vvv localhost` in your question. This will usually provide a clue as to why the connection was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is there in my case (nagios check_ssh connects but do not authenticate):

https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7014539

Comment: Please provide some details about the solution.

Comment: In my case was [icinga](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2), every some minutes login and run some tests